# Rebound doesn't work on a Rock Shox Recon Air

Tags: repair, fork, suspension

On my Trek Fuel Ex6 I have a Rock Shox Recon Air fork with rebound valve. The valve has a 2,5mm allen key for adjustment, but it seems broken. The [Trek Suspension Setup Guide](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/resources/suspension_setup) tells me to set the rebound to 8 clicks out, however if I turn the screw it does not click any more. Two months ago when I turned it it did click.

Any option to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**
The problem was in the screw. It was damaged. It wasn't griped. So the only solution was to carry it to a specialized bike store

Comment: Have you any hints that you *should* hear clicks, e.g. does the manual say so or has it clicked before? Or do you just think it should click but it doesn't? Have you tried turning the screw to its upper and lower limits and checking if that changes something in the fork's behaviour?

Comment: Bike is a Trek Fuel EX 6. Trek has a config web tool to setup suspensions. http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/resources/suspension_setup On front suspension said that I setup my fork with 8 clicks out. I tried to turning the screw to its upper and lower limit, but I don't hear clicks. 2 month ago I heard clicks. I suposse that allen wrench doesn't turn nothing.

Comment: Take a photo. I think the clicks should be generated by the red knob, that fits into the hex opening (though I have never seen/owned) a Reacon,

Answer (score 3):

Try to gently "tighten" the Allen setting all the way. Then try backing it out. I never hear clicks. I just feel them.

Answer (score 3):

Mine don't click. I have a red twisty knob on the bottom of the right leg.  The settings on mine only seem to take effect around the full mark. I back it off from  full to suit.